# Вызов функции несколько раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, работаю с jQuery, нужна помощь.
Нужно вызывать функцию, каждый раз разное кол-во раз.
Функция проводит вычисления и заносит в базу данных.
Одно срабатывание функции занимает от 30 секунд.
**Как вызывать функцию, что бы второй вызов не начинался пока первый не закончится?**
Думал через цикл while сделать, но он не ждет пока функция выполнится, и вызывает ее еще раз. Сделать false функцию не могу, т.к тогда браузер зависнет окончательно.

```
while (CountTr != 0) {
                var ds = 0 // номер tr из которой вытаскиваю ссылку для функции
                var game_table = main_table.children('tr').eq(ds).children('td:first').children('a').attr('href');
                var time = main_table.children('tr').eq(ds).children('td').eq(1).children('span').html();
                analitics (game_table, time); // сама функция которую нужно вызвать несколько раз
                CountTr = CountTr - 1; 
                $('#schet').html(CountTr); // отображение на какой итерации цикл
            }
```

Comment: http://js-help.net/text/function/recursivnie_function/recursivnie_function.php

Comment: Посмотрите [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/554291#554291). Там не совсем ваш случай - но вопрос как дождаться окончания выполнения асинхронной функции там рассматривается.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша функция работает долго и не является асинхронной, то ваш код должен работать верно (просто процесс будет "зависать" на время выполнении функции). Однако если у вас асинхронное выполнения (например ajax вызовы), то решение простое - это промисы ([читать тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)). Т.к. только механизм "обещаний" может четко определить что функция завершила свою работу (или нет)  для передачи управления дальше по коду.

Comment: сейчас учу промисы, если все получится, отмечу ответ правильным

Comment: Да я собственно не за отметкой бегу =) Мне важно, чтобы это помогло вам. К тому же там есть комментарий от Pavel Mayorov - там тоже полезный материал для изучения. Лучше всего если вы сможете разобраться с вопросом и ответить на него сами тут (заодно и я изучу мб что-то и мне не знакомо) =)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего перенести вызов новой итерации внутрь функции в коллбеке асинхронной части. В таком случае следующая итерация гарантировано будет после предыдущей.

```
var CountTr = n; // количество итераций
var ds = 0 // номер tr из которой вытаскиваю ссылку для функции
var game_table = main_table.children('tr').eq(ds).children('td:first').children('a').attr('href');
var time = main_table.children('tr').eq(ds).children('td').eq(1).children('span').html();

analitics(game_table, time, CountTr); //передаем CountTr в функцию

function analitics(game_table, time, CountTr) {
  $('#schet').html(CountTr); // отображение на какой итерации цикл

  // асинхронное тело функции

  analitics(game_table, time, --CountTr); // рекурсивно вызываем функцию с меньшим значением CountTr
}
```

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле эту задачку могут спросить на собеседованиях. Советую вам подробнее разобраться в этом вопросе. 
Для решения вам могут помочь Promise и Named Functions. Идея может выглядеть как то так:

```
// worker function
function rand() {
    return Promise.resolve(Math.random())
}

// main function
function runner(fun, times) {
    if (!times) { return }

    return fun().then( x => {
        console.log(x)
        runner(fun, times - 1)
    })
}

// async function call!
runner(rand, 3) /*.then() */
```

Но здесь не решена проблема с this и аргументами.

Answer (score -1):

как вариант

```
var work = false;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
if (work != true){
    work = true
    async(function () {
        work = false
    })
}
}, 1000)

function async(callback) {
    // тут что то делаем 30 секунд
    callback()
}
```